# Find indexes of specific strings in list

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of channels:

```
channels = ['1LT1', '1LT2', '1LT3', '1LT4', '1LT5', '2LA1', '2LA2', '2LA3', '3LH1', '3LH5', '4LT1', '4LT2', '4LT3', '5LH1', '5LH2', '4LT10']
```

I need to write an alogrithm to leave only distal channels. It means for each type of channel ('1LT', '2LA', '3LH', '4LT' and etc.) I need only channel with the highest last number.
 The best way is to return indexes of these channels. For example, for abovementioned list the results should be:

```
distal_i = [4, 7, 9, 14, 15]
```

I think I can do it with regexp by splitting like that:

```
labels = [re.findall('(\d+)(\w+?)(\d+)', channel) for channel in channels]
```

It gives me:

```
[('1', 'LT', '1'),
 ('1', 'LT', '2'),
 ('1', 'LT', '3'),
 ('1', 'LT', '4'),
 ('1', 'LT', '5'),
 ('2', 'LA', '1'),
 ('2', 'LA', '2'),
 ('2', 'LA', '3'),
 ('3', 'LH', '1'),
 ('3', 'LH', '5'),
 ('4', 'LT', '1'),
 ('4', 'LT', '2'),
 ('4', 'LT', '3'),
 ('5', 'LH', '1'),
 ('5', 'LH', '2'),
 ('4', 'LT', '10')]
```

But then I am really stuck.
Can somebody give me some tips to create good algorithm?

I am really thankful for any idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dict of tuples to keep track of the maximum number per channel type and the index of occurrence. The dict keys are ordered by their first insertions, but since you want the final order to follow where the occurrences of the maximum numbers are, the existing key should be deleted first in order for the new entry to be inserted at the right position whenever you find a new maximum number for a channel:

```
import re
d = {}
for i, channel in enumerate(channels):
    type, n = re.findall('\d+[A-Z]*', channel)
    n = int(n)
    if type in d:
        if n > d[type][0]:
            del d[type]
        else:
            continue
    d[type] = n, i
print([i for _, i in d.values()])
```

This outputs:

```
[4, 7, 9, 14, 15]
```

Note that dicts are only guaranteed to be ordered since Python 3.7. If you're using an earlier version, you can initialize `d` as a `collections.OrderedDict` instead:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your attempt, build a dictionary which holds the max value for each distal and the index, then map for the index.

```
import re

channels = ['1LT1', '1LT2', '1LT3', '1LT4', '1LT5', '2LA1', '2LA2', '2LA3', '3LH1', '3LH5', '4LT1', '4LT2', '4LT3', '5LH1', '5LH2', '4LT10']

highest = {}
for (i, c) in enumerate(channels):
    [[distal, num]] = re.findall('(\d+\w{2})(\d+)', c)
    if distal not in channels:
        highest[distal] = { 'idx': i, 'num': num }
    else:
        if highest[distal]['num'] < num:
            highest[distal] = { 'idx': i, 'num': num }

distal_i = [h['idx'] for _, h in highest.items()]
print(distal_i)
# [4, 7, 9, 14, 15]
```

Comment: This has a typo of misspelling `distal` as `d`, but even without the typo, this produces the result in an incorrect order (`[4, 7, 9, 15, 14]` rather than `[4, 7, 9, 14, 15]`) for reasons I have detailed in my answer. Also, the numbers should be converted to integers for numeric comparisons.